# How can I Make my module templates available to a theme

Tags: 7, theming

In my module I use `hook_theme` to specify some custom templates that I use.

they are stored here.

```
sites
 - all
  - modules
   - mymodule
    - mytemplatefile.tpl.php
```

Is there a way I can put `mytemplatefile.tpl.php` in the template directory and have my module use it.  I would like to be able to create the template file here so the designers can easily update it.

```
sites
 - all
  - theme
   - mytheme
    - mytemplatefile.tpl.php
```

I tried just copying it in there but my module still uses the template file in my module directory.

This is my Theme function

```
function bcscourses_theme(){
 //global $theme_path;  

$themes = array(
 'bcscourses' => array(
   'arguments' => array('Course' => array()),
  // 'path' => path_to_theme(),
   'template' => 'coursetheme'
 ),
 'bcscourses2' => array(
   'arguments' => array('Course' => array()),
   'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'aqua'),
   'template' => 'coursetheme2'
 ),     
 'bcscourses_title'=> array(
   'arguments' => array('CourseTitle' => NULL),
   //'path' => 
   'template' => 'coursetitle'
 ),

 'bcscourses_detailsblock' => array(
   'arguments' => array('Course' => array()),
  // 'path' => path_to_theme(),
   'template' => 'coursedetails_block'
 ),     
 );
// print_R($themes); 
 return $themes;

}
```

I could only get it to work by setting

```
 'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'aqua'),
```

When I don't set the path explicitly, it simply doesn't pick up the theme file, it will only pick up the module file.  I cleared caches every time.

Can this be done?

Comment: What you are doing should work. The template in the theme should override the one in the module. Did you clear the cache after adding the template file to the theme?

Comment: I did but I'll try again, thanks

Comment: If it still doesn't work, post your hook_theme() code in your question and check your logs for any errors.

Comment: @rooby I posted the hook_theme code.